# binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE

Tags: python, binance

I want to sell XRP/USDT. It is supposed I have more than the minimum, and even 49 XRP are more than 15usd.

Minimum: 0.10000000
XRP = 49.95301600

```
sym = 'XRP'
bol = 'USDT'
symbol = sym+bol

from binance.client import Client
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

# Minimum
minimum = client.get_symbol_info(symbol)
print(minimum['filters'][2]['minQty'])

quantity = client.get_asset_balance(asset=sym)['free']
print(quantity)

order = client.create_order(
    symbol=symbol,
    side=Client.SIDE_SELL,
    type=Client.ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
    quantity=quantity)
```

I get:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 1200, in create_order
    return self._post('order', True, data=params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 240, in _post
    return self._request_api('post', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 202, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 197, in _request
    return self._handle_response()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/binance/client.py", line 230, in _handle_response
    raise BinanceAPIException(self.response)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to call
`GET /api/v3/exchangeInfo`.
There you can find FILTER information for every Binance pair.
There are several filters for `XRPUSDT`. That one about `LOT_SIZE`

```
    {
      filterType: 'LOT_SIZE',
      minQty: '0.10000000',
      maxQty: '9000000.00000000',
      stepSize: '0.10000000'
    },
```

So you quantity step must me inside 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Binance trade rules](https://www.binance.com/en/trade-rule), and your original post, the minimum for XRP/USDT is 0.1, meaning that you cannot trade in less than 0.1 XRP quantities.

You should try truncating the quantity to one decimal place.

Comment: So should I set the quantity to 49.9 (one decimal)?

Comment: Something of that form, yeah. Since quantity is set to the full account balance, I suspect that Binance is returning that with full precision. You could try something like `quantity = math.trunc(quantity*10)/10`